# Is there a way where we could find the list of SharePoint sites that a specific SharePoint group has access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups

**Hi Everyone,**

I am working on a client request right now, and the client would like to know, as to which sites a particular SharePoint group has access permissions to?

For example, I need to know the list of SharePoint sites that SharePointGroupA has access.

Any insights or tips would be helpful!

Comment: How many site collections are there?

Comment: The SharePoint infrastructure we support has over a thousand of site collections. Thus, I need to find the list of sites that a SharePoint group only has access.